# Good practice: how to save many objects?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, entities

I have a question regarding a good practice: how to correctly save many objects?

Let's assume I modified many entities in a collection, let's say a collection of Products. This is what I could do:

```
...

foreach($productCollection as $product{
    $this->productRepository->save($product);
}

...
```

However using the method *save()* in a loop is not only a bad practice but also highlighted by PHP CS. Of course, if the collection only contains 4 or 5 products it won't change the face of the world, but sometimes it is clearly most than that.

I know that if I only modify an attribute, I don't need to use the repository and can use the built-in Magento component to update attributes, however sometimes I also need to do some logic and really need the product entity.

So anyone has a good practice to share in this context?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have to do a mass update of one (or more attributes) to the same value, you can use:

```
$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action')
    ->updateAttributes($productIds, ['status' => $status], $storeId);
```

In this example, we're updating all products matched by id ($productIds is array of product IDs), by setting their ***status*** attribute to the $status value, for store ***$storeId***.

If you want just to update single attribute in the collection of products, you can use (in your case):

```
...
foreach($productCollection as $product{
    $product->addAttributeUpdate($attributeCode, $value, $store);
}
...
```

***$attributeCode*** represents attribute name which has to be saved

***$value*** represents the value which you want to set on the entity

***$store*** represents store id, it can be $product->getStoreId()

Problem with ***addAttributeUpdate()*** is that updates attribute, but it doesn't update currently loaded product model. Take a look at the implementation in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`:

```
/**
 * Save current attribute with code $code and assign a new value
 *
 * @param string $code  Attribute code
 * @param mixed  $value New attribute value
 * @param int    $store Store ID
 * @return void
 */
public function addAttributeUpdate($code, $value, $store)
{
    $oldValue = $this->getData($code);
    $oldStore = $this->getStoreId();

    $this->setData($code, $value);
    $this->setStoreId($store);
    $this->getResource()->saveAttribute($this, $code);

    $this->setData($code, $oldValue);
    $this->setStoreId($oldStore);
}
```

In that case it's better to use something like, `productResource` is `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product` :

```
...
foreach($productCollection as $product{
    // its sugessted to inject resource as dependency than using deprecated getResource() method. 
    // check reference for more information.
    // $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, $attributeCode);
       $this->productResource->saveAttribute($product, $attributeCode);
}
...
```

Lack of this solution becomes visible when you're working on ***large collections***. That's why we have ***iterators*** which grabs data from database, one by one, and on that way, it prevents memory exhaustion.

```
...
$this->_dataObject = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

$iterator = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator')

$iterator->walk($productCollection->getSelect(), [[$this, 'walkCallback']]);
...

public function walkCallback($data)
{
    $this->_dataObject->reset(); // clean up shared object
    $this->_dataObject->setData($data['row']); // map data to product model
    $this->_dataObject->setDescription('test');
    $this->_dataObject->getResource()->saveAttribute($this->_dataObject, 'description'); // save only changed attribute instead of whole object
}
```

Those are ideas which you can use for manipulating collections.

Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento-coding-standard/pull/189